# Mathematica8: Finding maximum value of difference of two functions on [-1,1]

Tags: graph, wolfram-mathematica, max

I have two approximated functions and I want to find the maximum  value (error) between their graphs, to see how much they approach. I used :
FindMaximum[Abs[f[x] - p[x]], x],  but Mathematica 8 gave me that output: 
{2.75612*10^104, {x -> 2.75612*10^104}}

what does this mean? It is too big!

can you suggest me a better way?

Thanks

Comment: Post your functions! Your problem can be from easy to extremely hard depending on those kids.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell not knowing your functions, but I'd guess that the position of the maximum it found is well outside your intended domain. You may have more success using a different form or `FindMaximum`, namely

```
FindMaximum[Abs[f[x] - p[x]],{x,x0,xmin,xmax}]
```

where `x0` would be your initial guess for it (can be any point inside the region of interest), and `xmin,xmax` are the endpoints of your region of interest.

Comment: f[x] is a ordinary function and p[x] is a polynomial. i will run this command now. thanks

Comment: @nalkapo Well, then it is probably due to the polynomial, which is unbounded and monotonous at infinity. You should indicate the endpoints of your region, as I mentioned.

Comment: @nalkapo I think the key is what Leonid mentions in his comment above. If one of the functions is polynomial, so it _diverges_ as x->+/- Infinity (one power (ring :)) dominates them all). So probably your unexpected value is caused by considering an unbounded interval

Answer (score 2):

The reason is probably what Leonid said. To look at what FindMaximum is doing in real time, you can do

```
f[x_] := Sin[x];
p[x_] := x^2;
lst = {};
Monitor[
 FindMaximum[Abs[f[x] - p[x]], x, 
  EvaluationMonitor :> (AppendTo[lst, x]; Pause[.01])
  ], ListPlot[lst, PlotRange -> Full]
 ]
```

the vertical axis on the resulting plot is the x-coordinate FindMaximum is currently looking at. Once FindMaximum is done, the plot disappears; the list is stored in lst so you can eg ListPlot it.

You can also try this with `{Abs[f[x] - p[x]], -1 <= x <= 1}` as the argument, as suggested by Spencer Nelson, to see how the search proceeds then.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by some sort of overflow in one of the two functions when the input value of x is a very large number. You should restrict your domain to [-1, 1]:

```
FindMaximum[{Abs[f[x] - p[x]], -1 <= x <= 1}, x]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for a global maximum within the interval {a, b}, I suggest [NMaximize](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NMaximize.html):

`NMaximize[{Abs[f[x] - p[x]], a <= x <= b}, x]`.

Note that `FindMaximum` searches for any *local* maximum, which is only good if you know that, for your particular function, a local maximum would also be a global maximum.

Instead of the objective function `Abs[f[x] - p[x]]`, you may wish to use the objective function `(f[x] - p[x])^2`. This would make the objective function smooth (if `f[x]` and `p[x]` are smooth), which can help improve the efficiency of some numerical optimization methods.